# Graph Edit Distance with Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there any way to calculate similarity of graphs or the [graph edit distance](http://nlpr-web.ia.ac.cn/2010papers/%E5%BC%80%E6%94%BE%E8%AF%BE%E9%A2%98/%E5%9B%BD%E9%99%85%E5%88%8A%E7%89%A9/Xinbo%20Gao,%20A%20survey%20of%20graph%20edit%20distance.pdf) in Mathematica ?

Answer (score 4):

```
g1 = RandomGraph[{30, 50}];
g2 = RandomGraph[{30, 45}];
EditDistance[EdgeList[g1], EdgeList[g2]]
```

(* 49 *)

Comment: This is not the same as graph edit distance. For example, it won't be zero for isomorphic graphs.